# Sinch redirect call to loudspeaker android

Tags: android, call, sinch, speakerphone

I have created a calling app for android using `Sinch`. However I would like give the user the ability to take part in the call via loudspeaker.

I went through the documentation for a bit and thought that `Sinch` could not help me this but this is actually and android thing.

So how can I redirect a call to the loudspeaker upon a button press?

Answer (score 3):

Instance of sinch client has method to get audio controller. There you can find method for setting speaker enable/disable.

For my case:

```
mSinchClient.getAudioController().enableSpeaker();
```

Comment: The last time I visited Sinch docs I don't remember seeing an `AudioController` class. When was this class added?

Comment: You can check the sample codes provided by Sinch. Also documentation of Sinch very much straight forward. http://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/index.html?com/sinch/android/rtc/SinchClient.html

Comment: This method is not woking at all.